# Echo %variable% shows %variable% in MS-DOS 6.22

Tags: variables, batch-file, dos, virtual-pc

I have a problem with my virtual PC running on MS-DOS 6.22.
I need to use the variable `Date`, but I can't get it since whenever I try to echo a variable it shows `%variable%` instead.

I tried this on Windows console:

```
Set name=test
echo %name%
the result was "test"
```

When I tried it in the virtual machine i got `%name%` as a result.

Does anyone know how to resolve this please?

Comment: Try `echo %%name%%` or start your test in .bat file, not directly in console.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying.
I tried %%name%% and it didn't work, same for the .bat file.

I came here in the last resort.

Comment: In DOS I believe that `%var%` expansion only works in batch files, not at the command line directly.

Answer (score 3):

%Date% isn't part of MSDos 6.22. It only has the date command.

```
command /c echo. |date
```

Echos the date command

Comment: Hello there, thank you for you interest.
Actually I need to get the date in this format mm-dd-aaaa. To update a daily copy. 
How can I extract this from your command ? 

Have a nice day.